# XSLT: Взять из набора узлов каждые два

Tags: xml, xslt

Есть входной XML вида:

```xml
<items>
  <item id="1">111</item>
  <item id="2">222</item>
  <item id="3">333</item>
  <item id="4">444</item>
  <item id="5">555</item>
</items>
```

Нужно взять из набора каждые два узла, чтобы получить такой фрагмент HTML:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>ID 1: 111</p>
    <p>ID 2: 222</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ID 3: 333</p>
    <p>ID 4: 444</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>ID 5: 555</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Каким образом такое сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
<items>
  <item id="1">111</item>
  <item id="2">222</item>
  <item id="3">333</item>
  <item id="4">444</item>
  <item id="5">555</item>
</items>
```

код

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/items">
    <html>
      <head> <title>Testing XML Example</title> </head>
      <body>
        <ul>
        <li>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="item" />    
        </li>
        </ul>
     </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">

    <p>
      <xsl:text>ID </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
      <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p>
    <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
    </li>
    <li>
    </xsl:if>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

тут код

```
<xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
        </li>
        <li>
```

проверяет четность и пересоздает новый `<li>`

Comment: К сожалению, так не получится, т.к. это противоречит структуре XML. Нужен и открывающий, и закрывающий тег.

Comment: Тогда предлагаю сделать 2 проверки, если нечетное открываем, если четное закрываем.

Comment: Внутри узла может быть только закрытый узел, а тут получается один закрывающий тег и один открывающий. Было бы всё так просто =/

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что ответ на мой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454116/xslt-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5) поможет и вам. Как обычно все оказалось намного проще :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="items">
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="item[position() mod 2 = 1]">
                <li>
                    <p>
                        <xsl:text>ID </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
                        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </p>

                    <xsl:if test="self::node()[following-sibling::item]">
                        <p>
                            <xsl:text>ID </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::item/@id"/>
                            <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::item"/>
                        </p>
                    </xsl:if>
                </li>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```