# XSLT перебор узлов по длине

Tags: xml, xslt

Есть список названий:

```
<books>
    <book name="12345symbols"></book>
    <book name="123456789symbols"></book>
    <book name="12345symbols"></book>
    <book name="12345symbols"></book>
    <book name="12345symbols"></book>
    <book name="123456789symbols"></book>
    <book name="123456789symbols"></book>
    <book name="12345symbols"></book>
    <book name="12345symbols"></book>
    <book name="123456789symbols"></book>
    <book name="12345symbols"></book>
</books>
```

необходимо создать таблицу из двух столбцов:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="left">12345symbols</td>
        <td class="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">123456789symbols</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="left">12345symbols</td>
        <td class="right">12345symbols</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="left">12345symbols</td>
        <td class="right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">123456789symbols</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">123456789symbols</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="left">12345symbols</td>
        <td class="right">12345symbols</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">123456789symbols</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="left">12345symbols</td>
        <td class="right"></td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

Названия где меньше или равно 12 символов идут каждое в одной ячейке, по две ячейки в строке.
Если в названии больше 12 символов то ячейку растягиваем на две и делаем все в одну строку.

Уже третий день бьюсь над этой задачкой, может кто сможет что подсказать.
Если что то не понятно буду рад объяснить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вариантов всего 3, то проще всего навставлять if-ов

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <!-- xml -> html -->
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="books">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="book[1]" />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length(@name) &lt;= 12">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="string-length(following-sibling::book[1]/@name) &lt;= 12">

            <!-- два значения -->
            <tr>
              <td class="left">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
              </td>
              <td class="right">
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::book[1]/@name"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::book[2]" />

          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>

            <!-- одно + пусто -->
            <tr>
              <td class="left">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
              </td>
              <td class="right"></td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::book[1]" />

          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>

        <!-- одно на две ячейки -->
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::book[1]" />

      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Если больше - то вынести `apply-templates` за `choose` и добавить отдельные услови для пропусков нод.

Comment: Возможно это то что надо но сначала хотел уточнить, что есть "following-sibling", нигде в спецификациях такого не смог найти, можно ссылку на описание?

Comment: @VikingBO это одна из осей (axes) - направлений, в которых можно производить поиск - http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#axes

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли с решением этой задачки.
Хотел еще уточнить, можно ли сделать сортировку в данном примере? Например если будет еще один атрибут sort="" в котором будет указан порядок книг?

Comment: @VikingBO в этом примере сортировку вставить достаточно тяжело - books[1] не учитывает сортировку. проще отсортировать данные заранее.

Comment: Заранее это вы имеете ввиду при создании xml или это можно сделать прямо перед вызовом book[1] ?

Comment: @VikingBO при создании xml